# Parsing SAP web service in Android or iOS

Tags: android, ios, json

> I want to parse the web service in Android/iOS, Which is
> written in SAP, but not able to do that. Can I do this ? and How?

**When I hit the request on browser I get this popup and after entering the valid details here then only I get the JSON response, But how to get this done in mobile development?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add Authorization header to your request

```
Authorization: Basic <Base64of Username:Password>
```

For quick check, you can generate auth header [here](http://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/)

You can try using [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) chrome plugin to generate request and play with different set of input data.